# Time series prediction for three constrained variables (x+y+z=1)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

How can I PREDICT time-series for three non-negative variables that sum to 1? Say, x+y+z=1. I have historical data for x ,y, z , t. Based on historical data, I can create an ARIMA model for each variable individually, and make predictions for the future. How do I add the constraint ?

If this were only one variable, applying an ARIMA is simple.

For the single variable x(t), I can get a fit ARIMA_x(p, d, q) and those three numbers parametrize the model.

Here, I could get three sets of fits independently. But that is not proper.

With three variables that always sum to 1, how do I get three sets of constrained fit parameters?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html

Comment: Are you unable to make an ARIMA model for two variables taken together as a two-component vector?  Your ARIMA(...) notation suggests you are using software and most such software will allow applying the method to vectors of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Reduction of variables is a generic method to apply constraints.  We show this below and it is easy because ARIMA is indifferent to affine linear transformations.  However, at the end, we discover that we have just run ARIMA on two of the original variables and reconstructed the predictions of the third using the constraint.

Switch to a two variable system.  (Three variables minus one linear constraint leaves two independent degrees of freedom.)

A smart way to do this is to pick the point $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ as the origin and then pick two perpendicular unit vectors in that plane to be your new basis.

But I'm lazy and your ARIMA is indifferent to an affine linear transform, so the laziest thing to do is notice that points on your constraint is the plane through $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$.  So put the origin at $(1,0,0)$ and use $(-1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$ (the displacements from the first axis intercept to the second and third intercepts).  Let our new parameters be $u$ and $v$, so we have to solve
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} &= 
\begin{pmatrix}x-1\\y\\1-x-y\end{pmatrix}  \\
&= u \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + v \begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
giving the system \begin{align*}
1 - x &= u + v  \\
y &= u  \\
1 - x - y &= v  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so we can read off $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ in the second and third equations.  (And going the other way from the first two: $x = 1 - u - v$ and $y = u$.)

Now run your ARIMA on $u$ and $v$.  Then you can convert back to $x$ and $y$ and deduce $z = 1 - x - y$ to re-express results in the original variables.

But is all this necessary?  No.  Notice that we have $u = y$ and $v = z$.  That is, we can ignore one variable and run the ARIMA on the other two, then reconstruct the third variable using the constraint.

Comment: That is elegant. With two variables, (x,y), I would have just run ARIMA on one and assumed the other was (1-x).  For some reason, three made me balk.

Comment: What can you say about the error on the one that is not explicitly modeled- would you get identical predictions whether you eliminate x, y or z ?  Or does the one eliminated  accumulate more error?

Comment: @Dumbo : Do you have an exact constraint or an approximate constraint?  If it is an exact constraint, there is no error in the third variable (because it has no degree of freedom).  If it is an approximate constraint, then there are three degrees of freedom and we just have to run with the three variables.

Comment: It is an exact constraint. Say take a parking lot: x, y and z are fraction of the lot that is: empty, filled with cars, filled with trucks (assuming car and truck comprise the universe).  My hesitation probably comes from trying to reason, e.g. you can make assumptions about nature of car traffic or truck traffic more easily than say that of emptiness- this is saying it is just as easy to model emptiness and car as it is to model car and truck.

Comment: @Dumbo : Consider an error ellipsoid on the plane $x+y+z=1$.  Any realization of the error distribution is constrained to lie in the plane, so there are only two degrees of freedom of error.  You *could* marginalize the error onto the $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates, but this is a bit misleading -- it loses all the correlation information about the errors, that is, all the information that the errors must lie in the plane.  Choosing conservatively depends on what you are doing with the fit.

Comment: @ Eric Towers : What about doing the three series independently and then normalizing the sum to 1 at each future prediction step?

Comment: @Dumbo : Suppose the error was strictly an ellipse.  That is, there is some sequence of $(x,y,z)$ centers on the plane and each observation is on a translated copy of the same ellipse centered there.  If you normalize to one, you allow the radius of that ellipse to change in your predictions.  When you treat variables separately, you blind your predictor to constraints and correlations in the variables.  You still make predictions that are statistically valid, but they allow features absent in your data.  Here, you are putting energy into a third d.o.f. not present in your system.

Comment: @ Eric Towers : What if the sum of x +y becomes higher than 1 for a given time step? I know this shouldn't happen, and is problematic in its own right.  How do I fit in z ?

Comment: @Dumbo : From the text in your question, $z$ is negative for that time step.  Why would it not be?  I don't see that you have constrained any of the variables to be non-negative.  The simplest solution is to let your model violate the constraint (since your model has no mechanism to find and fit hard boundaries).  A simple solution is to clip the prediction to the nearest point on the boundary of the region.  A more complex solution alters the noise distribution to be location dependent, so the constraints can't be violated.

Comment: @ Eric Towers: x, y, z do have to be non-negative - I didn't mention explicitly, but these are ratios- that describe real natural non-negative quantities that add to 1. (Just edited the question to add non-negative x,y,z) . 

 Also, a problem related to this is : I have another decomposition of the same total into (X,Y,Z) and I have time series on those as well. Can I get better constraints by calculating the decomposition matrix time steps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324441/how-to-predict-evolution-of-correlation-matrix-as-time-series